# Error xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null ); al enviar datos GET en Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax

Estoy realizando una aplicación que utiliza ***like*** () a imágenes, hago las pruebas primero antes de implementar `ajax` y todo funciona bien pero cuando introduzco `ajax` me da el error siguiente en la consola:

> app.js:16571 GET http://aprendiendo-laravel.com.devel/like/undefined
>   500 (Internal Server Error)

Este es el código completo:

```
var url = 'http://aprendiendo-laravel.com.devel';
window.addEventListener("load", function(){

    $('.btn-like').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    $('.btn-dislike').css('cursor', 'pointer');

    //Boton de like
    function like(){    
        $('.btn-like').unbind('click').click(function(){
            console.log('like');
            $(this).addClass('btn-dislike').removeClass('btn-like');
            $(this).attr('src', 'img/hearts-purpura.png');

           $.ajax({
                url: url+'/like/'+$(this).data('id'),
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(response){
                    if(response.like){
                        console.log('Has dado like a la publucación');
                    }else{
                        console.log('Error al dar like');
                    }

                }
            });

            dislike();
        });
    }
    like();

    //Boton de dislike
    function dislike(){
        $('.btn-dislike').unbind('click').click(function(){
            console.log('dislike');
            $(this).addClass('btn-like').removeClass('btn-dislike');
            $(this).attr('src', 'img/hearts-blue.png');

            $.ajax({
                url: url+'/dislike/'+$(this).data('id'),
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(response){
                    if(response.like){
                        console.log('Has dado dislike a la publucación');
                    }else{
                        console.log('Error al dar like');
                    }

                }
            });

            like();
        });
    }
    dislike();
});
```

Comment: El problema parece estar en que `$(this).data('id')` te devuelve `undefined`. ¿A qué elemento se refiere `$(this)` en ese ámbito?

Comment: Gracias, El error estaba en que enviaba los datos undefined de mi url y no en el id de la imagen